# SwiftUI: strange errors with Toggle and Button

Tags: compiler-errors, boolean, swiftui, picker

I have a problem with this code. The error messages seems wrong, the Code should be right. But it won't work and I have no idea what the cause is. Can anyone give me a hint? First I tried this with Text instead of variables. Since I changed to Variables it won't work.
Target: I want to display 'DetailView' if a Button was tapped and get back some data from this View. Data entered with Toggle & PickerView (I haven't implemented the Picker yet, because of this errors). 
Here is the Code:

```
import SwiftUI

class HandoverData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var Befehl: String = ""
    @Published var WebLnk: String = ""
    @Published var bOnOff: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bToGo: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var HandOverData: HandoverData

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
            self.HandOverData.Befehl = "Text"
            self.HandOverData.WebLnk = "www.heise.de"
            Button(action: { //<= Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred 
                self.bToGo.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(HandOverData.Befehl)
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$bToGo) {
                DetailView(GetDat: HandOverData)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View{
    @ObservedObject var GetDat: HandoverData

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(GetDat.Befehl)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: self.GetDat.bOnOff) { <= 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Binding<Bool>'
                Text("An/Aus")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                let http = "https://"
                let url: NSURL = URL(string: http + self.GetDat.WebLnk)! as NSURL
                UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
            }) {
                Text(GetDat.WebLnk)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
            self.HandOverData.Befehl = "Text"
            self.HandOverData.WebLnk = "www.heise.de"
            Button(action: { //<= Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred 
                self.bToGo.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(HandOverData.Befehl)
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$bToGo) {
                DetailView(GetDat: HandOverData)
            }
        }
    }
```

you not able to execute any ordinary swift code!

```
self.HandOverData.Befehl = "Text"
self.HandOverData.WebLnk = "www.heise.de"
```

see some beginners tutorial about SwiftUI first.

int this part

```
Toggle(isOn: self.GetDat.bOnOff) { <= 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Binding<Bool>'
    Text("An/Aus")
 }
```

use

```
Toggle(isOn: self.$GetDat.bOnOff) { <= 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Binding<Bool>'
    Text("An/Aus")
 }
```

instead

Comment: Thank you. I had these courses, but i thought if `count += 1` is allowed, this should be too possible. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @Enrico you are not able to execute your code just because the closure is part of VStack structure initializer.

Comment: @Enrico if there is the statement like count += 1 in the source code, this is not because what expression is used there, but where.